# Comprimir archivos desde cmd sin instalar nada y que se nombre con la fecha y hora de la computadora

Tags: script, cmd

¿Cómo comprimir archivos vía cmd sin instalar nada en mi computadora y aparte que se nombre el archivo con la fecha y hora de mi computadora?

Adjunto parte de mi código, de momento sí me comprime los archivos pero no me crea el archivo comprimido y obviamente ni me los renombra con la fecha y hora.

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"

set "datestamp=%YYYY%%MM%%DD%" & set "timestamp=%HH%%Min%%Sec%"
set "fullstamp=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%_%HH%-%Min%-%Sec%"

echo datestamp: "%datestamp%"
echo timestamp: "%timestamp%"
echo fullstamp: "%fullstamp%"

compact C:\Users\aldai\OneDrive\Escritorio\Datos\%fullstamp%.zip /s C:\Users\aldai\OneDrive\Escritorio\Datos\*.txt
pause
```

Comment: "de momento si me comprime los archivos pero no me crea el archivo comprimido"... comprime o no comprime?

Comment: Comprime pero de 1 en 1 no me junta todos los archivos en uno solo

Comment: [COMPAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/compact) no genera archivos zip, es el método nativo de Windows para compresión de archivos NTFS. ¿Qué versión de Windows? ¿Se puede ejecutar script PowerShell? ¿Se puede ejecutar un compresor standalone junto al script o desde un recurso compartido? ¿Se puede usar otros formatos como [tar.gz](https://ss64.com/nt/tar.html) (Win10+)?

Comment: Existe alguna forma de generar el archivo zip desde cmd sin la necesidad de instalar alguna otra herramienta.

Comment: Emmanuel, ¿tu comentario es una pregunta o una afirmación?

Comment: Perdón se me paso poner los signos de interrogación, es una pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows [no puede de generar un zip nativamente desde cmd](https://serverfault.com/q/39071), a pesar de que zip está integrado en el explorador de archivos. Sin embargo si se puede hacer desde [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/compress-archive?view=powershell-7.3&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-6) o [vbscript](https://superuser.com/q/201371) o desde el [comando TAR](https://superuser.com/a/1473257) (Windows 10 o superior).

Una forma fácil de implementarlo en cmd **sin instalar nada**, puede ser usando el ejecutable standalone [7-Zip Extra](https://www.7-zip.org/download.html). Dentro del comprimido verás que hay varios archivos, pero solo necesitas **7za.exe**, colócalo junto al script cmd.

Para crear el zip cambiar la línea respectiva por algo como, obviamente reemplazando los valores por tus rutas de trabajo:

```
7za.exe a -tzip C:\Ruta-de-Archivos\%fullstamp%.zip C:\Ruta-de-Archivos\*.txt
```

---

En el caso de usar **tar**, Windows 10 (1803) o superior, podrías hacer algo como:

```
SET SRC=C:\Ruta-de-origen-de-los-datos
SET DST=C:\Ruta-de-destino-del-zip
cd %SRC%
tar.exe -a -cf %DST%\%fullstamp%.zip *.txt
```

Comment: De hecho ya estoy implementando el comando TAR, solo que este me guarda toda la ruta del archivo y no logro hacer que solo me guarde el archivo

Comment: @emmanuelmoyorido hice una modificación con el uso de TAR.