# Como evitar que el comando tar en windows me comprima toda la ruta del archivo?

Tags: windows, cmd, tar

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"

set "datestamp=%YYYY%%MM%%DD%" & set "timestamp=%HH%%Min%%Sec%"
set "fullstamp=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%_%HH%-%Min%-%Sec%"

echo datestamp: "%datestamp%"
echo timestamp: "%timestamp%"
echo fullstamp: "%fullstamp%"

tar cvf C:\Users\aldai\OneDrive\Escritorio\Datos\%fullstamp%.zip C:\Users\aldai\OneDrive\Escritorio\Datos\*.txt
pause
```

Ese es el código que estoy utilizando ya busque en Google pero no encuentro la forma de hacer que solo me guarde el archivo, en este caso serian todos los `.txt` que se encuentran en esa ruta.

Comment: En [la respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/602535/80870) que te di ayer coloqué una modificación para que no tenga ese comportamiento.

Comment: Me marca error "tar.exe: Failed to open 'C:\Users\aldai\OneDrive\Escritorio\Datos\2023-08-29_12-06-49.zip\2023-08-29_12-06-49.zip'"

Comment: Ese mensaje está indicando que el comando no está bien formado o las rutas no están colocadas correctamente. Por otro lado los argumentos están mal: debe ser `tar -a -cf ruta_de_salida.zip *.txt`, previamente se debe hacer un `cd directorio_de_trabajo` como puse en la respuesta. El argumento `-a` ([no documentado](https://superuser.com/a/898508)) usa el algoritmo **zip** y `-cf` crea el archivo.

Comment: Lo checo entonces, muchas gracias, saludos

Comment: @aeportugal listo ya quedo lo que andaba haciendo, gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Comprimir archivos desde cmd sin instalar nada y que se nombre con la fecha y hora de la computadora](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/602513/comprimir-archivos-desde-cmd-sin-instalar-nada-y-que-se-nombre-con-la-fecha-y-ho)

Comment: Si, eso responde a mi pregunta anterior